# Use a WCF service or REST api for JSON?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wcf, rest

I've just started working with SharePoint 2013 on a company that uses a WCF service to return JSON data with `.svc`-files and custom classes. I got the task to populate a table with items from a `List`, and without looking at how they did it I used jQuery and AJAX to call 
the

`http://sp/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('titlehere')/Items`

to display the data. This works fine for me, but I've seen in many places that people are using the url `http://sp/_vti_bin/Namespace/Service.svc/Method`, as is the case with the company I'm at.

What are the differences and when should the two be used? As far as I reckon, you can use the later to manipulate the data more exclusively than when doing simple CRUD operations on the `_api`, even though it seem to support alot of operations.

I read on a blog that `_vti_bin` is older aswell. Does that mean I should focus on using the `_api` instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you right, I guess custom WCF service (endpoint:`http://sp/_vti_bin/Namespace/Service.svc/`) is used to cover specific cases that does not seem possible to perform using standard SharePoint 2013 REST API or due to performance limitations.

But still, [SharePoint 2013 REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385%28v=office.15%29.aspx) (`_api`endpoint) should be considered  as a preferred choice for a list items manipulation.

For example, the article [Manipulating list items in SharePoint Hosted Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/02/22/manipulating-list-items-in-sharepoint-hosted-apps-using-the-rest-api.aspx) using the REST API gives an explanation how to perform CRUD operations in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

`_vti_bin` was used in SP 2010 and can be used in SP 2013 as well whereas `_api/web` is preferred in SP 2013 and is not available in SP 2010